# Cannot load in a large csv text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to load in a large csv file that has all the bitcoin trade data.  First I try to calculte the size of the data.  It does this by using a loop that increments' one to the size and stops when readline returns a null.
The csv file has 764732 lines of data.  My program only reads in the first 100000.  The last line matches the line kin my text editor (Komodo), which displays another 664732 lines of data.
Is there something wrong with my code, or is it java cannot handle a really big text file??
The code

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
for(int size=0; (line=br.readLine())!=null;)  
size++; 

br.close();
```

// last line is empty
   size--;

Comment: There is no specific maximum file size supported by Java. So definitely there something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare size field outside the loop and print afterwards.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
int size = 0;
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
 size++; 
}
br.close();
System.out.printf("%,d lines%n", size);
```

Max integer value (Integer.MAX_VALUE) is 2,147,483,647 so if you plan to read files with over 2 billion lines (that lines not bytes) then switch *int* to *long* type. Java can read very large files and *BufferedReader.readLine()* in particular can read very large files as long as the largest number of sequential characters between end-of-line markers fits into memory.

Answer (score 0):

- had size as a int works if I make size a long.  Looks like it was reading in all the data*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate number of lines in a file with Java, here's an example
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-lines-of-a-file-in-java/